# I can't register the user

Tags: json, flutter

the login method is working but the registration method does not work already I tried in many ways,

please would like a little knowledge of your excellence, thank you very much

repository to save to the database:

```
Future<User> register(User user) async {
  final String url = '${GlobalConfiguration().getString('api_base_url')}register';
  final client = new http.Client();
  final response = await client.post(
    url,
    headers: {HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json'},
    body: json.encode(user.toMap()),
  );
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    setCurrentUser(response.body);
    currentUser.value = User.fromJSON(json.decode(response.body)['data']);
  } else {
    throw new Exception(response.body);
  }
  return currentUser.value;
}
```

controller user:

```
void register() async {
    FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
    if (loginFormKey.currentState.validate()) {
      loginFormKey.currentState.save();
      Overlay.of(context).insert(loader);
      repository.register(user).then((value) {
        if (value != null && value.apiToken != null) {
          Navigator.of(scaffoldKey.currentContext).pushReplacementNamed('/Pages', arguments: 2);
        } else {
          scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
            content: Text(S.current.wrong_email_or_password),
          ));
        }
      }).catchError((e) {
        loader.remove();
        scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
          content: Text(S.current.this_email_account_exists),
        ));
      }).whenComplete(() {
        Helper.hideLoader(loader);
      });
    }
  }
```

erro:

```
E/flutter ( 7471): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/overlay.dart': Failed assertion: line 132 pos 12: '_overlay != null': is not true.
E/flutter ( 7471): #0      _AssertionError._doThrowNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:42:39)
E/flutter ( 7471): #1      _AssertionError._throwNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:38:5)
E/flutter ( 7471): #2      OverlayEntry.remove (package:flutter/src/widgets/overlay.dart:132:12)
E/flutter ( 7471): #3      Helper.hideLoader.<anonymous closure> (package:Imhungry/src/helpers/helper.dart:259:15)
E/flutter ( 7471): #4      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1180:38)
E/flutter ( 7471): #5      _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1077:19)
E/flutter ( 7471): #6      _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:979:7)
E/flutter ( 7471): #7      _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1019:23)
E/flutter ( 7471): #8      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1184:13)
E/flutter ( 7471): #9      _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1077:19)
E/flutter ( 7471): #10     _CustomZone.bindCallback.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1003:23)
E/flutter ( 7471): #11     Timer._createTimer.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/timer_patch.dart:23:15)
E/flutter ( 7471): #12     _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:398:19)
E/flutter ( 7471): #13     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:429:5)
E/flutter ( 7471): #14     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:168:12)
```

Comment: "Not work" meaning...? Do you get an error? If true, what error do you get?

Comment: error found above